# Formatting year month variable as date

Tags: datetime, time, stata, yearmonth

In Stata I have a variable `yearmonth` which is formatted as 201201, 201202 etc. for the years 2012 - 2019, monthly with no gaps. When I format the variable as

```
format yearmonth %tm
```

The results look like: `2.0e+05` for all periods, with the exact same number each time. A Dickey-Fuller test tells me I have gaps in my data (I don't) and a `tsfill` command generates dozens of empty observations between each period.

How do I properly format my `yearmonth` variable so I can set it as a monthly date?

Comment: You do have gaps — between 201212 and 201301, for example.  -gen wanted = ym(floor(yearmonth/100), mod(yearmonth, 100))- where the — are not to be typed. Then and only then will your -format- statement do you want. That command won’t create date variables. See -help datetime-.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have gaps — between 201212 and 201301, for example. Consider a statement like

```
gen wanted = ym(floor(yearmonth/100), mod(yearmonth, 100))
```

which parses your integers like 201201 into year and month components. So `floor(201201/100)` is `floor(2012.01)` and so `2012` while `mod(201201, 100)` is `1`. The two components are then the arguments of `ym()` which expects a year and a month argument.

Then and only then will your `format` statement do you want. That command won’t create date variables.

See `help datetime` in Stata for more information and  [Problem with displaying reformatted string into a four-digit year in Stata 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71623078/problem-with-displaying-reformatted-string-into-a-four-digit-year-in-stata-17) for an explanation of the difference between a date value and a date display format.